# icCube memory - how much is needed?

Tags: iccube

We've our data in a relational database and are wondering how much memory will icCube need. Let's assume my data is taking 10Gb in my database.

How can I know the amount of memory needed by icCube ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to determine in advance, this depends on:

- the amount of facts and measures
- the structure of your dimensions (affecting the size of the index)

The best you can do is build a small model (let's say using 1G of your data).

You can then load the schema/cube and check its statistics (Monitoring/Loaded Schema) that will display the amount of memory used by the dimensions, facts, and index. Then assuming your dimension are complete you can multiply by 10 the fact memory footprint to get an estimate of the required amount of memory.

[image]

Hope that helps.